# How to read track & field results from a website?

Tags: c++

I want to read track and field results from http://athletisme-quebec.ca/calendrier-et-resultats.php for members of my track & field team (I'm in charge of compiling statistics on the members).

I've written a program that adds/removes athletes and their results, and saves all the data in .txt files that can be retrieved every time we run the program. It then manipulates the data to get certain statistics I want.

I have the following classes that I need to fill with data from the websites (I omitted the methods here, since they're irrelevant to the question):

Base class Performance

```
class Performance {
private:
    string athlete_;
    string location_;
    int date_;
protected:
    string event_;
};
```

Derived class TrackPerformance

```
class TrackPerformance: public Performance {
private:
    PerformanceTime performanceTime_;
};
```

Derived class FieldPerformance

```
class FieldPerformance: public Performance {
private:
     double performanceResult_;
};
```

PerformanceTime class (uses double for math calculations, and string for display purposes & for entering times like 4:12.23 easily [it gets automatically converted to double, and vice-versa])

```
class PerformanceTime {
private:
    string performanceTimeStr_;
    double performanceTimeDbl_;
};
```

Athlete class that holds the performances of each athlete

```
class Athlete {
private:
    string name_;
    string gender_;
    map < string, vector <Performance*> > performances_; // the key is the event name
};
```

So, what would be the best way to do it? I tried finding an API to no avail.

They all follow a similar format, so I could open each event one by one and parse it using ifstream, but I want to know if there's a better way.

Example results: http://athletisme-quebec.ca/medias/resultsindoorchpt2016.htm

Comment: Is your question about how to download the data from the website using C++?  Or can you just browse there and hit save as and save the results in a local file?  Is your question about how to read the file after it is local?  I don't think there is a library for reading arbitrarily formatted data files...

Comment: Best case scenario, I want to be able to download all the data between two dates without downloading each file one by one. Then once it's on my local system to parse it into those Athlete objects.